# Python: Different methods to initialize 2D arrays gives different outputs

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I was solving a few questions involving dynamic programming. I initialized the dp table as -

```
n = 3
dp = [[False]*n]*n
print(dp)

#Output - [[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
```

Followed by which I set the diagonal elements to True using -

```
for i in range(n):
    dp[i][i] = True

print(dp)

#Output - [[True, True, True], [True, True, True], [True, True, True]]
```

However, the above sets every value in `dp` to True. But when I initialize dp as -

```
dp = [[False]*n for i in range(n)]
```

Followed by setting diagonal elements to True, I get the correct output - `[[True, False, False], [False, True, False], [False, False, True]]`

So how exactly does the star operator generate values of the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `dp = [[False]*n]*n`, you get a list of n of the **same** lists, as in, when you modify one, all are modified. That's why with that loop of `n`, you seemingly modify all `n^2` elements.

You can check it like this:

```
[id(x) for x in dp]
> [1566380391432, 1566380391432, 1566380391432, 1566380391432, 1566380391432] # you'll see same values
```

With `dp = [[False]*n for i in range(n)]` you are creating different lists `n` times. Let's try again for this `dp`:

```
 [id(x) for x in dp]
 [1566381807176, 1566381801160, 1566381795912, 1566381492552, 1566380166600]
```

In general, opt to use `*` to expand immutable data types, and use `for ...` to expand mutable data types (like lists).

Comment: Took me long enough but I guessed it right haha!! Nice answer +1.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that in the first example, you are not actually creating more lists.

To explain, lets go threw the example line by line.

First, you create a new list `[False]*3`. This will create  list with the value `False` 3 times.

Next, you create a different list with a *reference* to the first list. Note that the first list is not copied, only a reference is stored.

Next, by multiplying by 3 you create a list with 3 *references* to the same list. Since these are only references, changing one will change the others too.

This is why assigning `dp[i][i]=True`, you are actually setting all element i of all three lists to `True`, since they are all 3 the same list. Thus if you do this for all `i` all value in all (but there is only one) lists will be set to true.

The second option actually creates 3 separate lists, so the code works properly.